# Pandas Dataframe - How to combine multiple rows to one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in the form:

```
    A            B
0  30  60538815980
1  30   7410811099
2  26   2238403510
3  26   2006613744
4  26   2006618783
5  26   2006613743
```

I want to combine the rows where the value of A matches and produce something like that

```
            C_1         C_2         C_3         C_4
A                                                  
26   2238403510  2006613744  2006618783  2006613743
30  60538815980  7410811099         NaN         NaN
```

I have tried expressing it in terms of join or merge but have failed so far. Is there any simple way to express that or will I have to use apply and create a new DataFrame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, create a `groupby` object based on column `A`.  Then create a new dataframe `df2` which uses `ix` to index column `B` of each group based on the value `n` from column `A`.  Set the index of this dataframe equal to the key values from the `groupby` (i.e. the unique values from column `A`).

Finally, use a list comprehension to set the new column values equal to `C_1`, `C_2`, ..., etc.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [30, 30, 26, 26, 26, 26], 
                   'B': [60538815980, 7410811099, 2238403510, 
                         2006613744, 2006618783, 2006613743]})

gb = df.groupby('A')
df2 = pd.DataFrame([df.ix[gb.groups[n], 'B'].values for n in gb.groups], 
                   index=gb.groups.keys())
df2.columns = ["C_" + str(i + 1) for i in df2.columns]
df2.index.name = "A"

>>> df2
            C_1         C_2         C_3         C_4
A
26   2238403510  2006613744  2006618783  2006613743
30  60538815980  7410811099         NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd also recommend using `groupby` but I think we can use `pivot` to simplify things.  First, we create a new C column with the column labels we want to use, and then we call `pivot`:

```
>>> df["C"] = "C_" + (df.groupby("A").cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
>>> df.pivot(index="A", values="B", columns="C")
C           C_1         C_2         C_3         C_4
A                                                  
26   2238403510  2006613744  2006618783  2006613743
30  60538815980  7410811099         NaN         NaN
```