# Python3 Pandas - How to combine multiple rows to one

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Python Version:3.6
Pandas Version:0.21.1

How do I get from

print(df_raw)

```
  device_id  temp_a  temp_b  temp_c
0         0     0.2     0.8     0.6
1         0     0.1     0.9     0.4
2         1     0.3     0.7     0.2
3         2     0.5     0.5     0.1
4         2     0.1     0.9     0.4
5         2     0.7     0.3     0.9
```

to

print(df_except2)

```
      device_id  temp_a  temp_b  temp_c  temp_a_1  temp_b_1  temp_c_1  temp_a_2  \
    0         0     0.2     0.8     0.6       0.1       0.9       0.4       NaN   
    1         1     0.3     0.7     0.2       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
    2         2     0.5     0.5     0.1       0.1       0.9       0.4       0.7   

       temp_b_2  temp_c_2  
    0       NaN       NaN  
    1       NaN       NaN  
    2       0.3       0.9
```

Code of data:

```
    df_raw = pd.DataFrame({'device_id' : ['0','0','1','2','2','2'],
                       'temp_a'    : [0.2,0.1,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.7],
                       'temp_b'    : [0.8,0.9,0.7,0.5,0.9,0.3],
                       'temp_c'    : [0.6,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.9],
                  })
    print(df_raw)



     df_except = pd.DataFrame({'device_id' : ['0','1','2'],
                              'temp_a':[0.2,0.3,0.5],
                              'temp_b':[0.8,0.7,0.5],
                              'temp_c':[0.6,0.2,0.1],
                              'temp_a_1':[0.1,None,0.1],
                              'temp_b_1':[0.9,None,0.9],
                              'temp_c_1':[0.4,None,0.4],
                              'temp_a_2':[None,None,0.7],
                              'temp_b_2':[None,None,0.3],
                              'temp_c_2':[None,None,0.9],

                  })
    df_except2 = df_except[['device_id','temp_a','temp_b','temp_c','temp_a_1','temp_b_1','temp_c_1','temp_a_2','temp_b_2','temp_c_2']]
    print(df_except2)
```

Note:
1. **Number of Multiple rows is unknow.**
2. I refer to the following answer :
[Pandas Dataframe - How to combine multiple rows to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466827/pandas-dataframe-how-to-combine-multiple-rows-to-one)
But this answer just can deal with one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
g = df_raw.groupby('device_id').cumcount()
df = df_raw.set_index(['device_id', g]).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(i,j) if j != 0 else '{}'.format(i) for i, j in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  device_id  temp_a  temp_b  temp_c  temp_a_1  temp_b_1  temp_c_1  temp_a_2  \
0         0     0.2     0.8     0.6       0.1       0.9       0.4       NaN   
1         1     0.3     0.7     0.2       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2         2     0.5     0.5     0.1       0.1       0.9       0.4       0.7   

   temp_b_2  temp_c_2  
0       NaN       NaN  
1       NaN       NaN  
2       0.3       0.9
```

**Explanation**:

1. First count groups by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) by column `device_id`
2. Create `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and Series `g`
3. Reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html)
4. Sort second level of `MultiIndex` in columns by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)
5. Change columns names by list comprehension
6. Last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from index

Comment: Good Explanation!

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
import numpy as np
device_id_list = df_raw['device_id'].tolist()
device_id_list = list(np.unique(device_id_list))

append_df = pd.DataFrame()
for device_id in device_id_list:
    tmp_df = df_raw.query('device_id=="%s"'%(device_id))

    if len(tmp_df)>1:
        one_raw_list=[]
        for i in range(0,len(tmp_df)):
            one_raw_df = tmp_df.iloc[i:i+1]
            one_raw_list.append(one_raw_df)

        tmp_combine_df = pd.DataFrame()
        for i in range(0,len(one_raw_list)-1):
            next_raw = one_raw_list[i+1].drop(columns=['device_id']).reset_index(drop=True)
            new_name_list=[]
            for old_name in list(next_raw.columns):
                new_name_list.append(old_name+'_'+str(i+1))
            next_raw.columns = new_name_list

            if i==0:
                current_raw = one_raw_list[i].reset_index(drop=True)
                tmp_combine_df = pd.concat([current_raw, next_raw], axis=1)
            else:
                tmp_combine_df = pd.concat([tmp_combine_df, next_raw], axis=1)
        tmp_df = tmp_combine_df
    tmp_df_columns = tmp_df.columns
    append_df_columns = append_df.columns
    append_df = pd.concat([append_df,tmp_df],ignore_index =True)
    if  len(tmp_df_columns) > len(append_df_columns):
        append_df = append_df[tmp_df_columns]
    else:
        append_df = append_df[append_df_columns]
print(append_df)
```

Output:

```
  device_id  temp_a  temp_b  temp_c  temp_a_1  temp_b_1  temp_c_1  temp_a_2  \
0         0     0.2     0.8     0.6       0.1       0.9       0.4       NaN   
1         1     0.3     0.7     0.2       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2         2     0.5     0.5     0.1       0.1       0.9       0.4       0.7   

   temp_b_2  temp_c_2  
0       NaN       NaN  
1       NaN       NaN  
2       0.3       0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'device_id' : ['0','0','1','2','2','2'],
                   'temp_a'    : [0.2,0.1,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.7],
                   'temp_b'    : [0.8,0.9,0.7,0.5,0.9,0.3],
                   'temp_c'    : [0.6,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.9],
              })
cols_of_interest = df.columns.drop('device_id')
df["C"] = "C_" + (df.groupby("device_id").cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
df.pivot_table(index="device_id", values=cols_of_interest, columns="C")
```

Output:

```
            temp_a                 temp_b                   temp_c
    C       C_1     C_2     C_3     C_1     C_2     C_3     C_1     C_2     C_3
    device_id                                   
        0       0.2     0.1     NaN     0.8     0.9     NaN     0.6     0.4     NaN
        1       0.3     NaN     NaN     0.7     NaN     NaN     0.2     NaN     NaN
        2       0.5     0.1     0.7     0.5     0.9     0.3     0.1     0.4     0.9
```